# Javascript Promise doesn't wait for execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise, ethers.js

I'm building an app that interacts with smart contracts using ethers.js.

I would like to call a smart contract method (it returns a promise) and then after the execution doing some stuffs on the UI.

I did the following:

```
 async function getAllowance(address: string) {
try {
  if (contrastState != null) {
    return await signedTokenContract?.allowance(address, contrastState.address)
  } else throw new Error('Contract or signer is null or undefined check connect method results')
} catch (e) {
  console.log('connect error', e)
}
```

}

Then I use the method on the UI using the useLayoutEffect:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    async function initialize() {
      setLoading(true)
      const allowance = await getAllowance(address).then(allowance => {
        setAllowedNumber(allowance)
        console.log('Then allowance ' + allowance)
        setLoading(false)
      })
    }
    initialize()
  }, [])
```

The problem I experience is that the code in the then is called before the end of the promise, and then I get the following log:

```
'Then allowance: undefined'
```

I used promises many times. Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When handling promises, either use `async/await` or `then` syntax

```
const allowance = await getAllowance(address);
setAllowedNumber(allowance);

// OR

getAllowance(address).then(allowance => {
    setAllowedNumber(allowance);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However I tried both, but I get the same problem.

Comment: There could be a problem with `getAllowence` or your component state, please show the rest of your code. You can also try to save the result from calling `signedTokenContract?.allowance(address, address1)` and log it inside the function to see what you get.

Comment: I updated with the full method in the original question. 
I also performed the following: 
const r = signedTokenContract?.allowance(address, address1) 
console.log('resultset: ' + r) and the result is: 


resultset [object Promise]

Comment: Try `const r = await signedTokenContract(…)`

Comment: first time I refresh the page the result is: 
resultset undefined

Comment: if I change anythibng in the code and it fast refresh, the resultset is a number